# Kotlin - Expected a value of type Task<DriveFile>!

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to add a file to the app's AppFolder using this function:

```
private fun syncListToDrive() {
        val jsonList = Gson().toJson(activeSubs)

        val appFolderTask = mDriveResourceClient?.appFolder
        val createContentsTask = mDriveResourceClient?.createContents()
        Tasks.whenAll(appFolderTask, createContentsTask)
                .continueWithTask(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation<Void, Task<DriveFile>> {
                    override fun then(task:Task<Void>):Task<DriveFile> {
                        val parent = appFolderTask?.result
                        val contents = createContentsTask?.result
                        val outputStream = contents?.outputStream

                        val writer = OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)
                        writer.write(jsonList)

                        val changeSet = MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle("list")
                                .setMimeType("json")
                                .setStarred(true)
                                .build()

                        return mDriveResourceClient.createFile(parent!!, changeSet, contents)
                    }
                })
    }
```

specifically the `then` function has an error that the compiler describes as

> `Expected a value of type Task<DriveFile>!`

which to me looks like is just the one returned by the function. What am I missing?

Looking into the API I found out that the `createFile()` function returns a `Task<DriveFile!>!`

Comment: Is the api returning an optional?

Comment: @Submersed I'm not sure actually, if so I should be able to force it using '!!' at the end of the return statement right? This does not seem to work. The documentation for this API is still in Java only, so I'm trying to port it to kotlin

Comment: What version of the tasks api are you using?

Comment: @Submersed I imported this one 'import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks' and the gms version is the latest one, not quite sure what you mean

Comment: It's probably an issue with how generics are being used, since you're kind of trying to use a lamba(ish).  Have you tried just using Task.continueWith?

Comment: @Submersed Thanks for the help, but none of those were the problem. I managed to fix it in the end. If you are interested have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to use the [Object Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions)

by replacing:

```
Tasks.whenAll(appFolderTask, createContentsTask)
                .continueWithTask(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation<Void, Task<DriveFile>> {}
```

with:

```
Tasks.whenAll(appFolderTask, createContentsTask)
                .continueWithTask(object: com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation<Void, Task<DriveFile>> {}
```

I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the shortest form

```
Tasks.whenAll(appFolderTask, createContentsTask)
        .continueWithTask({ task ->

        })
```